# VSCode with PHP5

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpunit, php-5.6, test-explorer

I'm struggling with setting up environment for old tech project with PHP5.
My OS is Windows and I have installed so far VSCode plugins: `PHP Debug`, `PHP Intelephense`, `PHPUnit`, `PHPUnit Test Explorer`.
I downloaded `phpunit-5.7.27.phar` and configured VSCode according to documentation.

`Settings.json`

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php.exe",
    "phpunit.phpunit": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/phpunit-5.7.27.phar",
    "phpunit.php": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php.exe",
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "5.6.40",
    "intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
        "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/phpunit-5.7.27.phar",
        "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/php.exe",
        "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/"
    ]

}
```

`Launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 256,
                "max_data": 500,
                "max_depth": 3
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

What works for me fine is breakpointing on running app with xdebug and running unittests with `Cmd+Shift+P`.

What I need help with are as follows:

1. Code editor shows error for PHP unit classes and methods (even though unittests are executing fine as is). Do I need to add to path something besides `phar` file? Is VSCode non-compatible with phar files? The same happens for `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.
2. I can't figure out how to configure Test Explorer plugin to show nicely tests tree. Does it require some configuration in Launch.json? Launching tests with `Cmd+Shift+P` displays results only in terminal.

[image: Installed plugins and editor error on PHPUnit class]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) requires [installed PHPUnit with composer](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/902#issuecomment-567151328) in workspace.

   ```sh
   composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit
   ```
2. [PHPUnit Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=recca0120.vscode-phpunit) has by default `Phpunit: Files` setting set to `{test,tests}/**/*Test.php`, so changing it to proper glob should allow plugin to detect all tests.